# Play audio file associated with item in plist

Tags: swift, audio

I have audio in several places in my app, and most of it is straight forward and works fine such as

```
func ayuh() {
        do {
            audioPlayer =  try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("ayuhSound2", ofType: "mp3")!))
            audioPlayer!.play()

        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }
    }
```

Now I am trying to have audio files that are attached to particular questions in my plist play. I tried this:

```
 func nextQuestion() {
    let currentQuestion = mcArray![questionIdx]

    answers = currentQuestion["Answers"] as! [String]
    correctAnswer = currentQuestion["CorrectAnswer"] as? String
    question = currentQuestion["Question"] as? String

    cardButton.enabled = false
    titlesForButtons()
    self.bonusCoin.hidden = true
    //this code above works to bring up the question and various answers

    audio = currentQuestion["Audio"] as? String
    do {
        mcaudioPlayer =  try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(audio, ofType: "mp3")!))

        mcaudioPlayer!.play()

    } catch {
        print("Error")
    }

            mcaudioPlayer!.play()

        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }
```

but this only plays the first audio file in the list over and over for each question. 
[here are the audio files so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmAfm.png)

[I want the before_lepage.mp3 to play when this question appears from the array in my trivia app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDt6Y.png)

Any clues how I get it to play the audio file associated in the plist?

Comment: You'd better post the solution as an answer (yes, to your own question - it's allowed). This way you'll clearly indicate there is a solution and make your question even more useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working(with help from friends ;) )

```
func nextQuestion() {

        let currentQuestion = mcArray![questionIdx]

        answers = currentQuestion["Answers"] as! [String]

        correctAnswer = currentQuestion["CorrectAnswer"] as? String

        question = currentQuestion["Question"] as? String

        cardButton.enabled = false

        titlesForButtons()

        self.bonusCoin.hidden = true

        audio = currentQuestion["Audio"] as? String

        createPlayerItem(audio!, ofType: "mp3")

        queuePlayer.play()

        //queuePlayer.removeAllItems()

    }



    func createPlayerItem(item: String, ofType type: String) {

        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(item, ofType: type)

        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)

        let item = AVPlayerItem(URL: url)

        queuePlayer.insertItem(item, afterItem: nil)   

    }
```